# What is a good use case for the "all" event ...?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

in Backbone.

http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on

I have a single event bus with no namespacing.  I don't understand why you would need to use "all".

The example used in the notes is for a `proxy` but I don't understand why you would want to do this.

Comment: Straight from the fine manual: ["Any event that is triggered on a model in a collection will also be triggered on the collection directly, for convenience. This allows you to listen for changes to specific attributes in any model in a collection, for example: `documents.on("change:selected", ...)`"](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection). That's probably done using `'all'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this to let the user "something" is going on.  As a programmer I am also aware that Backbone is firing events.

You can use a subtle animation that shows the page is firing events.

It is also a good way to give a top level view of how your application is working.

Answer (score 2):

You can come up with different use cases, for example:

1. Logging all changes that happen on the object
2. Using it as Adapter from one framework to the other
3. Wrapping original object in proxy object, and triggering events through it
   e t.c.

It's up to you, if you need to use it or not, it's just there, with no obligations.